# Create a folder if it doesn't already exist

Tags: customization

I've run into a few cases with wordpress installs with bluehost where I've encountered errors with my wordpress theme because the uploads folder (wp-content/uploads) was not present.

Apparently the bluehost cpanel WP installer does not create this folder, though HostGator does.

So I need to add code to my theme that checks for the folder and creates it otherwise.

Comment: WordPress will attempt to create folder when it needs it, in the case that come to my mind, anyway. If the WordPress Core can't create the folder, I doubt that a function in your theme could.

Comment: Please elaborate on what your theme is trying to do and which specific errors it encounters. As above - WP always attempts to create the folder when code is trying to determine its location.